# Can't bind function that returns const char *

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

Using Boost.Python, I can't seem to be able to bind any function that returns a const char* example:

```
class Bar
{
 private:
   int x;
 public:
   Bar():x(0){}
   Bar(int x) : x(x) {}
   int get_x() const { return x; }
   void set_x(int x) { this->x = x; }
   const char *get_str(){return "hello";}
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(internal_refs)
{
   class_<Bar>("Bar")
      .def("get_x", &Bar::get_x)
      .def("set_x", &Bar::set_x)
      .def("get_str", &Bar::get_str, return_internal_reference<>())
      ;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/python/object/make_instance.hpp:27:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘assertion_failed(mpl_::failed************ boost::mpl::or_<boost::is_class<char>, boost::is_union<char>, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false> >::************)’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With boost 1.50, I am able to return `const char*` without needing to specify a CallPolicy.  The compile error you are receiving is a static assert, indicating that `return_internal_reference` is designed to be used for types that are either a class or union.  In this case, it is neither of those.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(internal_refs)
{
   class_<Bar>("Bar")
      .def("get_x",   &Bar::get_x)
      .def("set_x",   &Bar::set_x)
      .def("get_str", &Bar::get_str)
      ;
}
```

```
python
>>> from internal_refs import Bar
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.get_str()
'hello'
>>> type(b.get_str())
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: yup that works, so I don't need a return policy for const char * ? but how will boost know not to free that ? I mean is it safe ?  I've reading about return policies but I'm still not quite sure when use each one ?

Comment: It should be safe.  `boost::python` is handling the lower level details for types that it knows will be immutable.  In this case, it will allocate a `Py_String` object, populate it, then allow Python to manage it.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11144752/1053968) is an explanation that may provide some insight into why `return_internal_reference` requires class or union types.

Comment: Thanks, I will award your answer the bounty, but it says I must wait 21 hours, will do so tomorrow, thanks again for your help.